# HttpWebRequest Download always starts from begining of file not resuming

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add the pause/resume functionality of my download utility, and it seems  that the HttpWebRequest.Addrange() method doesn't work correctly. I tried to use it to resume a download but the webresponse always starts from the beginning of the file, each time i run my app.

Below is my code:

```
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
  request.AddRange((int)iExistLen);
  var downloadStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
     for (int byteSize = 0; (byteSize = fileProvider.Read()) > 0;)
            {
                downloadStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            };
```

Below is my Download URL:
    https://mathinew.blob.core.windows.net/sharedfolder/testfile006.txt

Please let me know if anybody faced the similar issue, or anything I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Hi, are you sure, that your server supports this feature? Not every server supports it.

Comment: Azure support Range header but not by default. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408927/do-http-range-headers-work-with-azure-blob-storage-shared-access-signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the URL I can see that you're using `Azure Blob Storage`.

By default it doesn't respect `Range` header and you need to set the version to 2011-08-18 or newer to make it work, using the `x-ms-version` header, for example:

```
request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2011-08-18";
```

You can also set the version globally for Range headers to be working by default, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408927/do-http-range-headers-work-with-azure-blob-storage-shared-access-signatures) and [this MSDN page](http://web.archive.org/web/20190118183517/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/09/15/windows-azure-blobs-improved-http-headers-for-resume-on-download-and-a-change-in-if-match-conditions/) for more info.

Comment: thanks @argaz, it works fine, But is this header applicable only for Azure blob or common for all URL types, because my client tool doesn't know the URL is for IIS/ Azure Blob/etc, i want to write the code unique for all type of URL, any suggestion or any more headers i need to set?

Comment: x-ms-version is specific for Azure blob, on most other servers the Range header should work unless the server doesn't support it at all.