# Video url hosted by azure media player not accepting media fragments

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, azure, blob

I am trying to load multiple videos hosted on Azure blob services with dynamically generated timestamps in my react app. The video element looks like this:

```
<div className="Player-video-container">
        <video
          id="vid1"
          className="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin"
          autoPlay
          controls={false}
          width="640"
          height="400"
          poster="poster.jpg"
          src={`${this.state.sourceUrl}#t=${this.state.startTime},${this.state.endTime}`}
        >
        </video>
      </div>
```

Example URL `https://astorageserver.blob.core.windows.net/video-storagea/603001712779238-toystory.mp4#t=20,25`

In theory this video that I hosted should load and begin playing at the 20 second mark and automatically pause at the 25 second mark. I have tested this on videos hosted elsewhere with success, but it starts at the beginning as if there's no media fragment. I also can't skip ahead or backwards in the video.

Example URL `https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/file_example_MOV_640_800kB.mov#t=20,25`

This link will correctly start at 20 seconds and pause at 25.

I am new to Azure hosting services and can't figure out a work around. The fragments need to be injected via the video source urls. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: Not an azure ninja myself, I regret, but from the sound of it what you want is to make your server support Range requests, and you indeed need it, because some browsers (Safari) do need this to play any media (not just to set fragments. Just found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408927/do-http-range-headers-work-with-azure-blob-storage-shared-access-signatures) don't know if it helps though...